# Approved edit on deleted post still awards +2 rep

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I was monitoring [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12855306) on a post that got deleted while the edit was in the review queue.

When the edit got approved the user was awarded +2 reputation, which does not make much sense since if the post would have been deleted after the edit was approved, the +2 rep would get reverted.

Note that the edit in question didn't show up anywhere in the user's profile (no mentions in the suggestion tab and revisions tab, and the total edit count stayed at 48), neither did the reputation change appear in the reputation tab. But the total rep went from 641 to 643.

In the meantime (two days later) the +2 has been reverted (by the rep recalculation script I guess?). Along with two other approved edits on post that got deleted. That's why the user has a total rep of only 637 now.

So everything is OK now, but why award the +2 in the first place?

**Edit:** As @animuson said, the actual issue is that the suggested edit is still in the queue after the post is deleted. The edit should automatically be discarded instead.

Comment: The actual "bug" here is that the system let that suggested edit continue collecting reviews for an hour after the post was deleted. They're supposed to stop accepting reviews immediately and get officially invalidated within ~15 minutes. An approved edit on an already-deleted post is never supposed to happen in the first place.

Comment: @animuson: I _think_ I have seen several of those recently: The review comes up with 3 buttons (Approve/Reject/Skip) instead of the usual 5.

Comment: @NisseEngström You are correct. I recently posted a screenshot in my one [MSE answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280739/323179). I didn't realize it was a bug.

Answer (score 24):

The post was not in the "deleted" state while being edited, because it was visible. The editor has made a fair contribution trying to improve the visible content. I do not see why his work should not be rewarded.

The requirement to guess if "makes no sense to edit" seems too complex and unnecessary.

Comment: How is this different from an answer on a deleted question?

Comment: The post has been deleted. The edit has been approved. Makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

> When the edit got approved the user was awarded +2 reputation, which does not make much sense since if the post would have been deleted after the edit was approved, the +2 rep would get reverted.

IMHO user deserves to get awarded, no matter what happened (or will happen) to the question.

+2 rep points are for the editing effort so even if the question was deleted before and it appeared in the queue, user that gains this rep made the task thus deserves this points.

Comment: That would seem to encourage the editing of off-topic questions and answers. Is that really a good use of editors and reviewers time?

Comment: The editor received (and then lost) the +2 rep, not the reviewer.  Of course the reviewer should still get credit towards the badge for performing the review task (in this case, rejecting because the edit did not redeem the post), but that isn't the question here.