# Why are we reviewing edits of deleted posts?

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues

I just reviewed the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15143525.

Strangely, there were only options to reject or accept, but not the buttons for "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit". My choice would have been to reject and edit since code formatting should be correctly fixed. I choose reject and tried to open the question directly, but it seems to be deleted.

Why was the post even present in the review queue when it was already deleted? Note, that this was not an audit.

Comment: Caching? Is the only thing to blame.

Comment: That was my first thought too. But the system seemed to know that the post was deleted (because it didn't show the edit buttons). Stating: "This question was deleted" would be ways better. Otherwise one has to read through the whole question which is a complete waste of time.

Comment: Maybe someone with enough reputation can see when the post was deleted compared to when the review happened.

Comment: Happened to me a few times as well. I guess the post was deleted while somebody else was already reviewing the edit, making it harder to remove it from the queue safely. (Still what _should_ be done IMO - I guess SO just hasn't yet gotten around to fix this case).

Comment: What should be done: In my opinion a message should be shown that the question was deleted. When now looking at the review one can see that another two users have gotten the same question to review after me.

Comment: Posts *do* get undeleted for various reasons - I know, I've undeleted a few of my own from time to time. As such, I can see why it is of some importance that any pending edits still get properly  reviewed.

Comment: Well, if someone undeletes their own question, it's usually because they are editing it themselves, so applying the pending edit as well would be confusing.

Comment: @MrLister No, they would see that their post has been edited and they would only be able to edit the already-changed post once the edits are approved. If the proposed edits have not been approved (or, unfortunately, if the OP has the old page open in their browser and hits edit without refreshing) they still get the old version.

Comment: Just reproduced, except in my case, I still have the "Improve edit" and "Reject and edit" options. Maybe it is related to having moderator privileges. Either way, we shouldn't be reviewing suggested edits on deleted posts. The deletion event should invalidate all pending suggested edits, just as it removes all rep gain from *approved* suggested edits.

Comment: This is confirmed to be a bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327301/approved-edit-on-deleted-post-still-awards-2-rep#comment363652_327301