# An edit suggestion at the time of deletion prevents edits on the deleted post

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, deleted-questions

If an edit was suggested and not approved before the post gets deleted then it is impossible to edit the post after it is deleted. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969422/how-can-i-resize-an-image-on-php

The suggested edit should be invalidated when the post is deleted.

Comment: I don’t think this works any differently than other edits, except your only options for review are Approve and Reject. It should be possible to edit the post after the suggestion is handled. See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343281/6083675

Comment: @Laurel How do I open the review item?

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely a bug. I wonder if this prevents the OP from making an edit. I doubt it, but if it does, that definitely needs to be fixed.

Comment: IIRC, suggested edits on deleted posts are invalidated by a task which runs on a periodic basis. I don't recall what the schedule is for that task. [The suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28695132) *should* be invalidated at some point. However, I *thought* that the schedule for the task was more often than the 4.5 hours which have passed as of now since the question was deleted. As a moderator, it looks like I could reject the edit, but, at least for now, I'm leaving it for a while to see if/when it's invalidated by the system.

Comment: @cigien In this case, the question was deleted by the author. Thus, the author would not be able to edit it anyway (i.e. authors can't edit questions which they delete).

Comment: @Makyen Oh, that's very interesting. I didn't think it would be any different for questions or answers, and I'm pretty sure I've edited answers that I've deleted. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @cigien Yes, it is different for questions and answers. If the author deletes their question, then they can't edit it. If the author delete their answer, then they can edit it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested edit appears to have been completed in review before it got invalidated, so we'll have to experiment with another post to see if there's a task that invalidates suggested edits on deleted posts.

Comment: @cigien Yes, unfortunately, someone decided that we would not get that information at this time. Next time, I guess I shouldn't link to the suggested edit. Or, at least, I've been assuming from the fact that you posted this question that you were unable to approve/reject the edit from the question page.

Comment: @Makyen Actually, Dharman posted the question, not me, but I can definitely confirm that I was unable to review the edit from the question page. I figured the users saw it in the review queues (assuming suggested edits on deleted posts even go through the queues). OTOH, I didn't try it from the link that you shared in the comment (not before it was approved anyway), so maybe that's how users got to review it.

Comment: @cigien Yep, I mistyped/misspoke.Dharman is, clearly, the author of the question. :; I had assumed that neither you (from your first comment), nor Dharman (from this question) could review the item on the question page. Thank you for confirming that was the case. I would have been interested to know if opening the "edit(1)" link in a new tab would have permitted you to review the edit. I consider it likely the first reviewer saw the review in the suggested edits queue, as they have a string of suggested edit reviews around that time, and the review was prior to my comment with the link.