# What is the correct response for a suggested edit review of a deleted post?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Closely related:

- [Why are we reviewing edits of deleted posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343281/why-are-we-reviewing-edits-of-deleted-posts)

Was working on some suggested edit reviews and I got one for a deleted post. Cool. I rejected the edit because it was wrong (random different user adding log message of unknown origin), but then I wondered -- how should I be reviewing these suggestions anyway?

Given a Suggested Edit review for a deleted post, should I:

- Review as normal, approving, rejecting, or editing as if it were a live/active/not-deleted post?
- Always reject, since the post is deleted and it doesn't matter? "No Improvement" as the reject reason fits, because you can't really improve something that's been deleted.

As an example, here's the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30313344) I reviewed, and the [deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925651/why-cant-i-upgrade-to-12th-angular) (10K+ only, clearly; but there's nothing to see here that's not in the suggestion ... no comments, no answers.)

Comment: I think it's a bug that should be fixed: remove from review all deleted post. It seems to be a [known bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327301/approved-edit-on-deleted-post-still-awards-2-rep#comment363652_327301) since a long time.

Comment: Aye, but the bug report on Meta SE is 6 years old, so I'm not going to hold my breath. The Suggested Edit queue has a max depth of 500 so these suggestions have to get dealt with sooner rather than a few years from now.

Comment: I've heard it's a resurfaced bug (you'd think they'd have regression tests for it by now...). No one is gonna complain if you handle it as you'd normally would. Also means that if the post gets undeleted, the suggested edit does become useful

Comment: @Zoe Was there a post announcing they’d changed it? I feel like I have seen reviews for deleted posts the entire time I have been reviewing but they are infrequent enough that I wouldn’t have noticed that they were just gone for awhile.

Comment: Yeah I was under the impression they'd never addressed it. I've waded through about 8 different bug reports/questions on both Metas and haven't found anything indicating it was ever addressed.

Comment: @BSMP when I said "I've heard", I mean that I vaguely remember I may or may not have heard it from someone somewhere. Read: I don't have a canonical source

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just review them as you normally would. If the system doesn't care that the post has been deleted, then you shouldn't, either.